# iPhone : adjust sound equalizer settings - Does Apple authorize it?

Tags: iphone, settings, equalizer, adjustment, bass

Quick question:

**Does Apple authorize an application to adjust the sound equalizer settings**, i.e. modify the bass, middle and treeble levels as we want?

I see that only predefined equalizer settings are provided thought the iPhone settings.

Answer (score 0):

Im checking this solution here and I dont think there's any chance of been rejected:

[How to achieve Equilizer Setting for iPhone in Audio Player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171206/how-to-achieve-equilizer-setting-for-iphone-in-audio-player)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Do you think the equalizer can only process the sound played by your own application or can it process any sound of other applications like a standard audio player?